# K8s pvc MountVolume.MountDevice failed

Tags: kubernetes

On my kubernetes cluster I'm running a pod, which has a postgres db (gitea). I'm using longhorn.

A few days ago, the pod went down and has been restarted on another worker. But now I do get the error

```
MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-c00153a0-66d2-4644-a400-a036d4dc9d28" : rpc
error: code = InvalidArgument desc = volume pvc-c00153a0-66d2-4644-a400-a036d4dc9d28 hasn't been attached yet
```

The PVC is still existing with exact this name. Deleting the pod will restart the pod, but still the same error. What is causing the error?